# LOGBACK - Roll files based on size and then roll all of them together in compressed folder at end of day

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have a requirement in which I have to roll files based on below requirements :

1. roll files when they reach their limit of 1 KB (putting 1 kb for testing purpose only). EG : log.1.txt, log.2.txt. It could be multiple in a day.
2. roll all the files created in that day and compress them (in gz format).
   So basically both of the log.1.txt, log.2.txt will be stored in logs.json.date.gz format.

But after exploring I sense that it is not possible since it might need 2 triggering policies.

Below is my code snippet :

```
<appender name="jsonAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>log/logs.json</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log/logs.json.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>1KB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
            <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
            </jsonFormatter>
            <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

To all the logback experts, please guide me if my understanding is correct. Whether this scenario is possible or not.

UPDATE : This question is different from the other questions posted here. I want to roll files based on size which is size wise rolling. And then at midnight  roll them together in a common folder which will be done by time based rolling.

So I dont want log19august.01.gz and log19august.02.gz. 
I want log.01 and log.02 to go under log19august.gz.

So this is not a duplicate question as it needs size and time based rolling but in different scenario.

Comment: Couldn't you use two appenders added to same logger?

Comment: so in that case 2 appenders would be writing to same file. Is this approach correct?

Comment: @ZqBany I pondered over ur apporch. could not come up with solutions. Please share some more details.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I edited it, its not a duplicate.

Comment: @LuisMunoz an explanation would be nice why it is marked as duplicate. I edited this question and provided all needed details. I have already gone through the question which is added here, mine has different requirement. I urge you to read the different requirements. And give me a reason why you mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @LuisMunoz, either I am not able to make you understand the language to show you how it is different. But I have given examples too to show how it is different. Please share more details on this.

Comment: Ok, will revert my vote np. However, I don't think logback will compress all the logs at midnight, you will have to do that yourself with an script or write a custom RollingPolicy.

Comment: @Onki Two appenders - one is writing all messages to single file rolled over at midnight and another is writing to different set of files rolled over size (with maxHistory set to 1). However you will have duplicates for current day. You can also use SizeAndTimeBased rolling policy with folder per day `<fileNamePattern>/%d{dd-MM-yyyy}/log.%i</fileNamePattern>` but you will have to write an crontab script to gzip that folders. You can also write custom RollingPolicy to meet your criteria